How do I know when my COM object is released?
I'm implementing drag and drop and clipboard copy/paste with CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS with IStream. So I implemented my own IStream where basically I map the stream to a .NET FileStream object.
But how do I know when to clean up my internal FileStream object?
I know COM calls IUnknown.Release() when it's finished with an object, but when I want to implement that, I also have to implement the rest of the IUnknown interface, while otherwise .NET handles it for me.
Can I have .NET call IDisposable.Dispose() when my COM object is released? Or is there a way to override the standard .NET IUnknown.Release() method?
This is my IStream adapter: (now I open and close the FileStream constantly)
    Public Class StreamAdapter
        Implements IStream

        Private _filePath As String
        Private _fileStream As FileStream
        Private _position As Long = -1

        Public Sub New(filePath As String)
            _filePath = filePath
        End Sub

        Private Sub openStream()
            If _fileStream Is Nothing Then
                _fileStream = New FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                If (_position = -1) Then
                    _fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
                Else
                    _fileStream.Seek(_position, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub closeStream()
            _position = _fileStream.Position
            _fileStream.Dispose()
            _fileStream = Nothing
        End Sub

        Public Sub Read(pv() As Byte, cb As Integer, pcbRead As IntPtr) Implements IStream.Read
            openStream()

            If _fileStream.Position + cb > _fileStream.Length Then
                cb = _fileStream.Length - _fileStream.Position
            End If

            Dim bytesRead As Integer
            If cb > 0 Then
                bytesRead = _fileStream.Read(pv, 0, cb)
            End If

            If pcbRead <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, bytesRead)
            End If

            closeStream()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Write(pv() As Byte, cb As Integer, pcbWritten As IntPtr) Implements IStream.Write
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Seek(dlibMove As Long, dwOrigin As Integer, plibNewPosition As IntPtr) Implements IStream.Seek
            openStream()

            Select Case dwOrigin
                Case 0 ' STREAM_SEEK_SET
                    _fileStream.Seek(dlibMove, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                Case 1 ' STREAM_SEEK_CUR
                    _fileStream.Seek(dlibMove, SeekOrigin.Current)
                Case 2 ' STREAM_SEEK_END
                    _fileStream.Seek(dlibMove, SeekOrigin.End)
                Case Else
                    Throw New NotSupportedException()
            End Select

            If plibNewPosition <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, _fileStream.Position)
            End If

            closeStream()
        End Sub

        Public Sub SetSize(libNewSize As Long) Implements IStream.SetSize
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub
        Public Sub CopyTo(pstm As IStream, cb As Long, pcbRead As IntPtr, pcbWritten As IntPtr) Implements IStream.CopyTo
            openStream()

            If cb = -1 Then cb = Long.MaxValue
            Dim endPosition As Long = Math.Min(_fileStream.Position + cb, _fileStream.Length)
            Dim bytesRead As UInt64 = 0
            Dim bytesWritten As UInt64 = 0
            Dim ptrWritten As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Of Integer))
            While _fileStream.Position <> endPosition
                cb = Math.Min(endPosition - _fileStream.Position, 1024 * 1000)
                Dim pv(cb - 1) As Byte
                bytesRead += _fileStream.Read(pv, 0, cb)
                pstm.Write(pv, cb, ptrWritten)
                bytesWritten += Marshal.ReadInt32(ptrWritten)
            End While
            pstm.Commit(0)

            If Not IntPtr.Zero.Equals(pcbRead) Then
                Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbRead, bytesRead)
            End If
            If Not IntPtr.Zero.Equals(pcbWritten) Then
                Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbWritten, bytesWritten)
            End If

            closeStream()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Commit(grfCommitFlags As Integer) Implements IStream.Commit
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Revert() Implements IStream.Revert
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub LockRegion(libOffset As Long, cb As Long, dwLockType As Integer) Implements IStream.LockRegion
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub UnlockRegion(libOffset As Long, cb As Long, dwLockType As Integer) Implements IStream.UnlockRegion
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Stat(ByRef pstatstg As STATSTG, grfStatFlag As Integer) Implements IStream.Stat
            openStream()

            ' Provide information about the stream
            pstatstg.cbSize = _fileStream.Length
            pstatstg.type = 2 ' STGTY_STREAM (Stream)

            closeStream()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Clone(ByRef ppstm As IStream) Implements IStream.Clone
            Throw New NotSupportedException()
        End Sub
    End Class


The COM Callable Wrapper (CCW) implements IUnknown and deals with reference counting. You cannot, so far as I'm aware, get involved in this process. Unfortunately, for various reasons, CCWs don't check for/call IDisposable.Dispose - see this question for more details on that. So the short answer is you don't.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Re getting involved in the process, see Marshal.ReleaseComObject and Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject.  But I don't think that's the kind of involvement requested here.
